# Travelling to Canada; in eTA, passport number is lower case

Tags: passports, eta

I recently got Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA) approved to travel to Canada by air. One thing I worry is that one alphabet letter in my passport number in the eTA approval email is not capitalized. Should I reapply for the eTA in this case?

Comment: I don't know for sure but it seems _extremely_ unlikely that the passport number is case-sensitive.